# connect ec2 and rekognition in aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How to remove the php fatal error?

This is the code of AWS (ec2-os-linux) to get the image in Amazon Rekognition when given to EC2.

This is the error which is occurring:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient::__construct() must be an instance of Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface, array given, called in /var/www/html/face/index.php on line 43 and defined in /var/www/html/face/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php:73
>
> Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/html/face/index.php(43): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient-> __construct(Array)
>   #1 {main}
>     thrown in /var/www/html/face/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php on line 73

My code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient;


$bucket = 'aws-webinar-ethnus';
$keyname = 's.jpg';

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'region'    => 'us-east-2',
    'version'   => '2006-03-01',
    'signature' => 'v4'
]);

try {
    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket'        => $bucket,
        'Key'           => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'    => __DIR__. "/$keyname",
        'ACL'           => 'public-read-write'
    ]);

    // Print the URL to the object.
    $imageUrl = $result['ObjectURL'];
    if($imageUrl) {
        echo "Image upload done... Here is the URL: " . $imageUrl;

        $rekognition = new RekognitionClient([
            'region'    => 'us-east-2',
            'version'   => 'latest',
        ]);

        $result = $rekognition->detectFaces([
            'Attributes'    => ['DEFAULT'],
            'Image' => [
                'S3Object' => [
                    'Bucket' => $bucket,
                    'Name'  =>  $keyname,
                    'Key'   =>  $keyname,
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        echo "Totally there are " . count($result["FaceDetails"]) . " faces";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your exception has line numbers but your code listing doesn't. Which line of code triggers the exception?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)